# Joining these two specific tables

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I have encountered a interesting problem today (or so it seems to me) and I thought it would be productive to share it.

I have two database tables with the following construct:

**Table 1: mod_class**

```
class_id
CSD2311 
CSD2314
CSD12
```

**Table 2: m_classes_enrolled_in**

```
student_id   class_id
5            CSD2311
5            CSD2314
```

So the first table has all possible  class_id's and the second one has class_id's and the student that is enrolled in that class. I would like to create a list of all classes that the student is **not enrolled in**. So far a left-join looked really nice but it seems impossible to display it in this way:

```
SELECT mod_enrolled_in.class_id 
FROM mod_enrolled_in 
WHERE student_id <> 5 
INNER JOIN mod_class 
ON mod_enrolled_in.class_id = mod_class.class_id
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do that several ways

1)

```
Select class_id from mod_class
EXCEPT
    Select class_id From m_classes_enrolled_in WHERE student_id = 5
```

2)

```
Select class_id from mod_class
Where class_id NOT IN 
      (Select class_id From m_classes_enrolled_in WHERE student_id = 5)
```

3)

```
Select class_id from mod_class m
LEFT JOIN 
    (Select class_id From m_classes_enrolled_in WHERE student_id = 5) cs
    ON m.class_id = cs.class_id
WHERE cs.class_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Quite complete answer. Thank you it did the job!

Answer (score 1):

This is what you are looking for.

```
SELECT mod_enrolled_in.class_id 
FROM mod_enrolled_in 
LEFT JOIN mod_class 
ON mod_enrolled_in.class_id = mod_class.class_id
WHERE class_id != 5 
AND mod_class.class_id is NULL
```

Comment: I tried the same before it didn't work. Thank you for the answer anyways.

Comment: Try now..! I edited the post. Sorry didn't read the entire question on the first occasion. :P

Answer (score 1):

Don't you want to `LEFT JOIN` `mod_class` so you can do an anti-join?

```
SELECT mod_class.class_id
FROM mod_class
LEFT JOIN mod_enrolled_in ON (mod_class.class_id = mod_enrolled_in.class_id
AND mod_enrolled_in.student_id = 5)
WHERE mod_enrolled_in.class_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT c.class_id
FROM mod_class c

LEFT OUTER JOIN mod_enrolled_in e
ON e.class_id = c.class_id
AND e.student_id = ?

WHERE e.student_id IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:-

```
Select class_id from mod_class
Where class_id NOT IN (Select class_id From m_classes_enrolled_in)
```

See this [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0f849/1)